# Missing precise interests(keywords) in facebook ads targeting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I created several ads via Facebook Ads API with 4 precise interests (keyword) and when I query them back I saw that only 2 precise interests were actually attached.

The original precise was:
Aeronautics, Algebraic structure, Analytical chemistry, Atmospheric pressure

The precise that actually added to the ads :
Aeronautics, Analytical chemistry

How can it be ? Am I missing something?

Comment: did you use the ID of the interest when creating the target spec or just the name?

Comment: Just the name. I think I figured it out.. Could it be that "Algebraic structure" and "Atmospheric pressure" defined in the new precises?